# Android add views, one next to other horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I have a question that for some with experience may sound stupid, but I can't solve the problem.

I want to add views, one next to other, horizontally, in a scroll view.
Can anyone recommend me how to make views to arrange horizontally?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the views have to be dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? These `TextViews` will scroll horizontally:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I had to change from "match_parent" to "fill_parent" for 1.6